# Regex to match string with 3/4 sub pattern

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have the following regex:

```
#^(?=.{8,20})(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*\W).*$#
```

This regex matches a string that contains at least one each of the groups a-z A-Z 0-9 and special chars.

Is it possible to write a regex to match at minimum 3 from 4 sub pattern (One preg_match, not multiple) ?

For example, the string should match A-Z, 0-9 and a-z **or** A-Z, 0-9 and a special char.
But also 4/4 should be allowed.

Comment: Is this for a password policy?

Comment: @Jack: Your edit broke the regex. Mine was just cosmetic.

Comment: @TimPietzcker The original Markdown had backslashes as well.

Comment: @Jack: You removed all the `*`...

Comment: @TimPietzcker Hmm, indeed. My bad :(

Comment: @Jack, exactly, it's for a password policy.
The backslashes were wrong, i just added them because stackoverflow printed the regex bold^^ 
See my solution bellow.

Comment: @raffis: This is easily solvable with loop. Regex is not too efficient for stuff like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can have only three out of four conditions, just write an alternation with all possibilities:

```
/^(?:(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])|(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\W)|...|...|...).{8,20}$/
```

I just wrote 2 alternatives, too complicated. You need to fill the `...` parts by yourself.

**I would suggest you don't do that with a single regex. It gets complicated and is error prone. Test the conditions separately and count how many are matched.**

Comment: `.*^` is not a problem (but useless).

Comment: @TimPietzcker my concerns were more about the `\#` parts, but it seems it was only in the original question source code, but not displayed. Only when I edited the regex to be code formatted, the backslashes occured. It assume they are not in the OPs original code.

Comment: Ehm without the backslashes at the beginning and the end. I just add them to escape the # for stackoverflow... but yes the regex works.

Ah got it, just add all possible solutions with |. But that is a huge regex^^:
#^(?:(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])|(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*\W)|(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\W)|(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\W)(?=.*[0-9])|(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*\W)|(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*\W)(?=.*[A-Z])|(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*\W)(?=.*[A-Z])|(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*\W)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])
).{8,20}$#

But it's working :)

Comment: @raffis, because of that I would suggest to split it up in different tests.

Comment: Yes probably, but I can't change my code in the current release, so I need to configure what I have :)